# A matrix form used in the Quantum Annealer Eigensolver (QAE)

Tags: quantum-chemistry, python, pyscf, excited-states, quantum-computing

In the paper "[Computing molecular excited states on a D‑Wave quantum annealer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00162)", PySCF is employed to compute the TDA matrix. Then a few of the lowest eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a TDA matrix are computed using the Quantum Annealer Eigensolver (QAE). How can I get the specific "A matrix" mentioned, which appears to be the singular matrix for the TDA computation?" @Nike Dattani

Answer (score 4):

## Introduction

The TDA (Tamm-Dancoff approximation) uses only the $A$ matrix, which is the upper-left block of the full TD-DFT matrix that was provided [by Tyberius here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12077/5), in his answer to your question about how to interpret the $A$ matrix output from [this Python script](https://github.com/tepl/pyscf/blob/master/examples/tddft/21-matrix_A_B.py) as a 2D array. Now it seems that you not only want to interpret the $A$ matrix as a 2D array, but you also want to "get" the $A$ matrix:

> "How can I get this specific 'A matrix' mentioned"

I was able to obtain an $A$ matrix from exactly that same Python script (called `21-matrix_A_B.py` and titled `A, B matrices of TDDFT method`) , and I have simplified it further so that you only get the `A` and `B` matrices (see below).

## Import some basic modules

First import some basic modules that tend to be used for TD-DFT calculations:

```
import numpy
from pyscf import gto, scf, dft, tddft
```

## Specify the molecule, geometry and basis set

Then "build" an HF (hydrogen fluoride) molecule with a bond length of 0.917 in PySCF's default distance units, and the 6-311G* basis set:

```
mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = [
    ['H' , (0. , 0. , .917)],
    ['F' , (0. , 0. , 0.)], ]
mol.basis = '6311g*'
mol.build()
```

## Run an SCF calculation

In the above-linked example Python script provided with PySCF, an RHF calculation is done first (but examples using UHF and UKS are provided later, and we can just choose one of them):

```
mf = scf.RHF(mol).run()
```

Notice that I skipped some lines from the example script:

```
def diagonalize(a, b, nroots=5):
    nocc, nvir = a.shape[:2]
    a = a.reshape(nocc*nvir,nocc*nvir)
    b = b.reshape(nocc*nvir,nocc*nvir)
    e = numpy.linalg.eig(numpy.bmat([[a        , b       ],
                                     [-b.conj(),-a.conj()]]))[0]
    lowest_e = numpy.sort(e[e > 0])[:nroots]
    return lowest_e
```

I skipped those lines because we are not actually going to use that `diagonalize` function, and in the paper that you mentioned, the function of the "diagonalization" (which in this case is to give us the eigenvalues), is attempted by the D-Wave annealer rather than by PySCF.

## Get the A and B matrices

```
a, b = tddft.TDHF(mf).get_ab()
```

Let's also borrow the following lines from the function `diagonalize` that we removed, since this will actually reshape the `a` array (which is a 4-dimensional array when obtained directly from `get_ab()` in the above line of code) into a more familiar 2D matrix:

```
nocc, nvir = a.shape[:2]
a = a.reshape(nocc*nvir,nocc*nvir)
```

## Putting it all together

After entering the command `python` or `python3` in a terminal, assuming that it is installed with one of those names, and that suitable versions of `numpy` and `pyscf` are installed properly, you can run the following commands:

```
import numpy
from pyscf import gto, scf, dft, tddft

mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = [
    ['H' , (0. , 0. , .917)],
    ['F' , (0. , 0. , 0.)], ]
mol.basis = '6311g*'
mol.build()

mf = scf.RHF(mol).run()
a, b = tddft.TDHF(mf).get_ab()
nocc, nvir = a.shape[:2]
a = a.reshape(nocc*nvir,nocc*nvir)
```

Then when I enter the command `a` in the Python console, I get the following 2D matrix:

```
array([[ 2.60456133e+01, -1.43048216e-01,  9.17722977e-17, ...,
        -1.35695829e-02, -1.44171241e-17, -1.80327561e-17],
       [-1.43048216e-01,  2.62987754e+01,  5.04602697e-16, ...,
        -8.91049840e-03, -1.75270105e-17, -1.19651301e-17],
       [ 9.17722977e-17,  5.04602697e-16,  2.66653809e+01, ...,
        -2.05590505e-16,  1.36131946e-04, -1.30126224e-02],
       ...,
       [-1.35695829e-02, -8.91049840e-03, -2.05590505e-16, ...,
         6.55286894e+00,  5.26486912e-17,  5.92386345e-17],
       [-1.44171241e-17, -1.75270105e-17,  1.36131946e-04, ...,
         5.26486912e-17,  6.56828103e+00, -5.35839140e-04],
       [-1.80327561e-17, -1.19651301e-17, -1.30126224e-02, ...,
         5.92386345e-17, -5.35839140e-04,  6.80976592e+01]])
```

Without including the last two lines of the `code` in this section, there will be an enormous amount of numbers that are not expressed in a clear way:

```
array([[[[ 2.60456133e+01, -1.43048216e-01,  2.52247100e-16, ...,
           1.18048394e-16, -1.02366899e-01, -2.99273826e-03],
         [ 5.63225509e-03,  8.76294620e-03, -2.72961492e-17, ...,
          -9.29391367e-18,  1.21119261e-02,  1.50477775e-02],
         [-5.47818937e-03, -1.00965081e-02,  2.32057657e-17, ...,
           1.14199267e-17, -1.63499987e-02, -8.27876810e-03],
         [-1.53313386e-17, -1.21786734e-17, -1.17585782e-02, ...,
          -1.43825277e-02, -2.26920292e-17, -3.12834270e-17],
         [ 4.52641078e-17,  2.05773995e-17,  1.63839318e-03, ...,
           2.65783872e-03,  2.02358655e-17,  7.37224457e-19]],

        [[-1.43048216e-01,  2.62987754e+01,  1.85559485e-16, ...,
           8.69255890e-18, -1.80038437e-01,  2.76640714e-03],
         [ 1.06229812e-02,  1.51471459e-02, -3.25023819e-17, ...,
          -3.42704358e-18,  2.10369804e-02,  9.47115809e-03],
         [-3.26220325e-03, -1.36594196e-02,  1.34144430e-17, ...,
           7.48984986e-18, -1.53972648e-02, -9.58464325e-03],
         [-5.04372963e-18, -2.65822744e-17, -5.55759927e-03, ...,
          -9.44432054e-03, -2.60031530e-17, -2.52199046e-17],
         [ 1.91883698e-17,  6.69254025e-17,  7.74373617e-04, ...,
           1.74527603e-03,  3.11500512e-17,  9.65125128e-19]],

        [[ 2.52247100e-16,  1.85559485e-16,  2.66653809e+01, ...,
          -4.14258055e-01,  3.88019883e-16, -1.68771690e-16],
         [-5.49768644e-17, -5.27252681e-17,  4.73023040e-02, ...,
           4.07441054e-02, -4.20031262e-17,  6.34145865e-17],
         [-2.36590108e-17, -2.52329213e-17, -1.25044647e-02, ...,
          -1.01253886e-02, -5.33239060e-17,  6.85749494e-18],
         [ 3.07973972e-03,  8.05746451e-03, -1.11839463e-16, ...,
          -9.51809153e-17,  1.59090454e-04, -1.52071873e-02],
         [-4.29118594e-04, -1.12269482e-03,  1.19373172e-16, ...,
           7.41740010e-17, -2.21670265e-05,  2.11890856e-03]],

        ...,

        [[ 1.18048394e-16,  8.69255890e-18, -4.14258055e-01, ...,
           3.13177514e+01, -1.06879611e-16,  4.89758197e-16],
         [-2.40137843e-17, -1.45581683e-17,  1.01366432e-01, ...,
           1.08418144e-01,  8.40920174e-18,  1.99334109e-17],
         [-2.25365451e-17, -3.09943397e-17, -2.68050363e-02, ...,
          -2.66715970e-02, -5.84272882e-17,  1.20879344e-17],
         [ 1.85007711e-02,  1.99998116e-02, -6.27379629e-17, ...,
          -1.46358495e-16,  1.95846665e-04, -3.08303159e-02],
         [-3.41887510e-03, -3.69589233e-03,  8.57034652e-17, ...,
           2.29138501e-16, -3.61917502e-05,  5.69733006e-03]],

        [[-1.02366899e-01, -1.80038437e-01,  3.88019883e-16, ...,
          -1.06879611e-16,  3.14873810e+01, -2.71828309e-03],
         [ 4.38904519e-02,  6.16691287e-02, -1.01488685e-16, ...,
           1.80700152e-17,  1.06739839e-01, -4.44639257e-03],
         [ 4.34057139e-03, -2.36002189e-02,  1.71053614e-18, ...,
          -6.42770021e-18, -2.76086222e-02, -2.51608621e-02],
         [-2.83982709e-18, -2.29817728e-17,  2.20942868e-03, ...,
           3.56382552e-03, -1.08377845e-16, -2.49025578e-17],
         [ 1.38145177e-17,  3.29116066e-17, -3.07852940e-04, ...,
          -6.58581972e-04,  2.14013831e-16,  1.62670658e-18]],

        [[-2.99273826e-03,  2.76640714e-03, -1.68771690e-16, ...,
           4.89758197e-16, -2.71828309e-03,  9.20697384e+01],
         [ 6.74990646e-03,  5.38580972e-03,  5.11377035e-18, ...,
           1.39336016e-17,  9.96971178e-03,  6.84327263e-04],
         [ 6.70688000e-03,  1.26288908e-02, -4.39000556e-17, ...,
          -7.18892160e-17,  8.88532442e-02,  1.82547204e-03],
         [-1.55201670e-17, -2.92650713e-18,  2.83491517e-02, ...,
           1.03861543e-01,  8.12772173e-17,  3.16651901e-16],
         [-2.27258802e-18, -5.28719242e-18, -3.95005722e-03, ...,
          -1.91932348e-02, -3.46312768e-17,  4.02013294e-16]]],


       [[[ 5.63225509e-03,  1.06229812e-02, -5.49768644e-17, ...,
          -2.40137843e-17,  4.38904519e-02,  6.74990646e-03],
         [ 1.43064975e+00, -6.09615429e-02,  1.22200625e-16, ...,
           5.19826520e-17, -2.87950614e-02, -8.67487755e-03],
         [-1.35359294e-03,  1.48416197e-02, -8.84029921e-17, ...,
          -2.54479702e-17,  3.96865233e-02,  3.40996999e-03],
         [ 6.65558163e-18,  1.34296339e-17,  4.80030137e-02, ...,
           4.60463491e-02,  4.02892829e-17,  3.66728694e-17],
         [-4.57741656e-18, -9.69989436e-18, -6.68854761e-03, ...,
          -8.50919755e-03, -2.57769958e-17,  2.64951838e-18]],

        [[ 8.76294620e-03,  1.51471459e-02, -5.27252681e-17, ...,
          -1.45581683e-17,  6.16691287e-02,  5.38580972e-03],
         [-6.09615429e-02,  1.73075386e+00,  3.42004217e-17, ...,
          -7.37769300e-18, -5.04545009e-02, -3.99341689e-03],
         [ 1.21996710e-02, -8.32910442e-03, -6.73292146e-17, ...,
          -1.66368347e-17,  3.35308950e-02,  1.71042301e-03],
         [ 7.69442487e-18,  2.62887641e-19,  5.29991463e-02, ...,
           2.85696738e-02,  2.80316603e-17,  2.49191624e-17],
         [-3.59978088e-18, -9.52942963e-18, -7.38468872e-03, ...,
          -5.27957162e-03, -2.31599852e-17,  1.32364578e-18]],

        [[-2.72961492e-17, -3.25023819e-17,  4.73023040e-02, ...,
           1.01366432e-01, -1.01488685e-16,  5.11377035e-18],
         [ 1.22200625e-16,  3.42004217e-17,  2.25094001e+00, ...,
          -1.47944383e-01,  1.40541678e-16, -7.95333140e-18],
         [ 1.21471608e-17,  1.32223282e-17,  1.02704171e-02, ...,
           1.37344572e-02,  1.17888453e-17,  1.41476791e-17],
         [-9.07439459e-03,  1.43740515e-02,  2.27439404e-17, ...,
           4.25652937e-17,  1.36933468e-03, -4.73928990e-03],
         [ 1.26438979e-03, -2.00282275e-03, -8.68165242e-18, ...,
          -2.70587404e-17, -1.90797609e-04,  6.60353668e-04]],

        ...,

        [[-9.29391367e-18, -3.42704358e-18,  4.07441054e-02, ...,
           1.08418144e-01,  1.80700152e-17,  1.39336016e-17],
         [ 5.19826520e-17, -7.37769300e-18, -1.47944383e-01, ...,
           7.36556571e+00, -4.39735115e-17,  2.43640327e-16],
         [-8.04429959e-18, -1.24842003e-18,  1.60052076e-02, ...,
           4.40198712e-02,  2.43777713e-17, -3.22449155e-17],
         [ 8.01692312e-03, -9.04851396e-03,  3.77793961e-17, ...,
           7.52233837e-17,  1.35174553e-03,  2.84855602e-02],
         [-1.48149818e-03,  1.67213241e-03, -2.16513251e-17, ...,
          -3.95632533e-17, -2.49797649e-04, -5.26402774e-03]],

        [[ 1.21119261e-02,  2.10369804e-02, -4.20031262e-17, ...,
           8.40920174e-18,  1.06739839e-01,  9.96971178e-03],
         [-2.87950614e-02, -5.04545009e-02,  1.40541678e-16, ...,
          -4.39735115e-17,  7.52836414e+00,  1.36660153e-03],
         [ 1.79537429e-02,  4.07133045e-02,  1.07757677e-18, ...,
          -4.92690958e-18,  5.39443678e-02,  2.97677086e-02],
         [ 1.32749938e-17,  2.60329833e-17,  8.84724119e-03, ...,
           1.52561546e-02,  5.91020123e-17,  3.25611936e-17],
         [-3.02944995e-18, -6.65286767e-18, -1.23273914e-03, ...,
          -2.81928179e-03, -4.17740399e-17, -5.40082544e-18]],

        [[ 1.50477775e-02,  9.47115809e-03,  6.34145865e-17, ...,
           1.99334109e-17, -4.44639257e-03,  6.84327263e-04],
         [-8.67487755e-03, -3.99341689e-03, -7.95333140e-18, ...,
           2.43640327e-16,  1.36660153e-03,  6.91485902e+01],
         [-9.47212208e-03, -1.84883621e-02,  7.70047505e-17, ...,
           1.34478914e-17, -3.48847080e-02,  5.40926289e-02],
         [ 1.12904045e-18, -1.27254220e-17, -4.30316058e-02, ...,
          -4.53776133e-02, -3.74021590e-17, -5.06419642e-17],
         [ 3.82585897e-19,  4.14226871e-18,  5.99585156e-03, ...,
           8.38561761e-03,  1.55155698e-17, -3.41171246e-17]]],


       [[[-5.47818937e-03, -3.26220325e-03, -2.36590108e-17, ...,
          -2.25365451e-17,  4.34057139e-03,  6.70688000e-03],
         [-1.35359294e-03,  1.21996710e-02,  1.21471608e-17, ...,
          -8.04429959e-18,  1.79537429e-02, -9.47212208e-03],
         [ 6.09789250e-01, -1.86455048e-02,  1.39133141e-17, ...,
           3.35324507e-17,  4.30784404e-03,  3.77835830e-03],
         [ 6.84680539e-18,  3.32719551e-17,  7.33231010e-02, ...,
           3.36192439e-02,  3.13760901e-17,  3.21225801e-17],
         [ 5.34778447e-18, -2.74096172e-18, -1.02165471e-02, ...,
          -6.21271380e-03, -1.27902235e-17,  4.73676722e-18]],

        [[-1.00965081e-02, -1.36594196e-02, -2.52329213e-17, ...,
          -3.09943397e-17, -2.36002189e-02,  1.26288908e-02],
         [ 1.48416197e-02, -8.32910442e-03,  1.32223282e-17, ...,
          -1.24842003e-18,  4.07133045e-02, -1.84883621e-02],
         [-1.86455048e-02,  1.01481374e+00, -9.98893495e-17, ...,
          -3.94572513e-17,  6.09524778e-03,  5.44665749e-03],
         [ 3.51011460e-17,  5.98611131e-17,  1.03744415e-01, ...,
           6.09961875e-02,  6.10726210e-17,  5.14665331e-17],
         [ 6.91639776e-18, -1.03426735e-18, -1.44553312e-02, ...,
          -1.12718732e-02, -1.55470256e-17,  1.09268624e-17]],

        [[ 2.32057657e-17,  1.34144430e-17, -1.25044647e-02, ...,
          -2.68050363e-02,  1.71053614e-18, -4.39000556e-17],
         [-8.84029921e-17, -6.73292146e-17,  1.02704171e-02, ...,
           1.60052076e-02,  1.07757677e-18,  7.70047505e-17],
         [ 1.39133141e-17, -9.98893495e-17,  1.41802681e+00, ...,
          -1.25562022e-01, -8.88889602e-17, -1.02861495e-17],
         [ 4.45574189e-03, -1.11762802e-04, -3.42445837e-16, ...,
          -2.38046403e-16,  5.73656461e-03,  9.55766799e-04],
         [-6.20845224e-04,  1.55725811e-05,  6.67430243e-17, ...,
           6.27926127e-17, -7.99309931e-04, -1.33172717e-04]],

        ...,

        [[ 1.14199267e-17,  7.48984986e-18, -1.01253886e-02, ...,
          -2.66715970e-02, -6.42770021e-18, -7.18892160e-17],
         [-2.54479702e-17, -1.66368347e-17,  1.37344572e-02, ...,
           4.40198712e-02, -4.92690958e-18,  1.34478914e-17],
         [ 3.35324507e-17, -3.94572513e-17, -1.25562022e-01, ...,
           6.59519507e+00, -1.26641103e-16,  2.36026923e-16],
         [-1.44929563e-03,  2.69522248e-03, -8.13496236e-17, ...,
          -1.06114358e-16,  3.33108195e-04, -6.58471582e-03],
         [ 2.67824552e-04, -4.98067295e-04,  3.18508566e-17, ...,
           7.22678661e-17, -6.15571808e-05,  1.21683149e-03]],

        [[-1.63499987e-02, -1.53972648e-02, -5.33239060e-17, ...,
          -5.84272882e-17, -2.76086222e-02,  8.88532442e-02],
         [ 3.96865233e-02,  3.35308950e-02,  1.17888453e-17, ...,
           2.43777713e-17,  5.39443678e-02, -3.48847080e-02],
         [ 4.30784404e-03,  6.09524778e-03, -8.88889602e-17, ...,
          -1.26641103e-16,  6.86839820e+00,  9.62470577e-03],
         [-1.96578472e-18,  2.88324223e-17,  1.11512001e-01, ...,
           1.39832846e-01,  1.07534704e-16,  1.12056604e-16],
         [-5.05176956e-19, -7.31259464e-18, -1.55376354e-02, ...,
          -2.58406006e-02,  9.49891379e-18, -3.17451065e-18]],

        [[-8.27876810e-03, -9.58464325e-03,  6.85749494e-18, ...,
           1.20879344e-17, -2.51608621e-02,  1.82547204e-03],
         [ 3.40996999e-03,  1.71042301e-03,  1.41476791e-17, ...,
          -3.22449155e-17,  2.97677086e-02,  5.40926289e-02],
         [ 3.77835830e-03,  5.44665749e-03, -1.02861495e-17, ...,
           2.36026923e-16,  9.62470577e-03,  6.83443677e+01],
         [-1.54075432e-18, -7.77028709e-19,  1.15440493e-02, ...,
           1.23731435e-02,  1.50073155e-17,  3.67158060e-17],
         [-1.15520124e-18, -2.38172811e-18, -1.60850158e-03, ...,
          -2.28651184e-03,  3.47233490e-18,  8.34355852e-17]]],


       [[[-1.53313386e-17, -5.04372963e-18,  3.07973972e-03, ...,
           1.85007711e-02, -2.83982709e-18, -1.55201670e-17],
         [ 6.65558163e-18,  7.69442487e-18, -9.07439459e-03, ...,
           8.01692312e-03,  1.32749938e-17,  1.12904045e-18],
         [ 6.84680539e-18,  3.51011460e-17,  4.45574189e-03, ...,
          -1.44929563e-03, -1.96578472e-18, -1.54075432e-18],
         [ 4.60301317e-01, -8.14036526e-02,  1.78095753e-16, ...,
           4.77920265e-17, -2.55815025e-02,  2.91869574e-03],
         [ 7.69357549e-17,  3.95568941e-17, -9.16038717e-18, ...,
          -3.68031176e-18,  1.34909040e-17, -1.54482510e-18]],

        [[-1.21786734e-17, -2.65822744e-17,  8.05746451e-03, ...,
           1.99998116e-02, -2.29817728e-17, -2.92650713e-18],
         [ 1.34296339e-17,  2.62887641e-19,  1.43740515e-02, ...,
          -9.04851396e-03,  2.60329833e-17, -1.27254220e-17],
         [ 3.32719551e-17,  5.98611131e-17, -1.11762802e-04, ...,
           2.69522248e-03,  2.88324223e-17, -7.77028709e-19],
         [-8.14036526e-02,  7.71163480e-01,  1.21861621e-16, ...,
           3.49655673e-17, -5.06584131e-02,  6.40882246e-03],
         [ 2.85414463e-17,  1.32604673e-16, -7.54993775e-18, ...,
          -1.71380598e-17,  3.86065675e-17,  5.28608203e-19]],

        [[-1.17585782e-02, -5.55759927e-03, -1.11839463e-16, ...,
          -6.27379629e-17,  2.20942868e-03,  2.83491517e-02],
         [ 4.80030137e-02,  5.29991463e-02,  2.27439404e-17, ...,
           3.77793961e-17,  8.84724119e-03, -4.30316058e-02],
         [ 7.33231010e-02,  1.03744415e-01, -3.42445837e-16, ...,
          -8.13496236e-17,  1.11512001e-01,  1.15440493e-02],
         [ 1.78095753e-16,  1.21861621e-16,  1.47986648e+00, ...,
          -9.88879943e-04,  2.62220010e-16,  1.27034545e-16],
         [-1.10886189e-17, -2.68748156e-17, -2.94424850e-02, ...,
          -2.65470468e-02, -5.64843710e-17,  1.08869356e-17]],

        ...,

        [[-1.43825277e-02, -9.44432054e-03, -9.51809153e-17, ...,
          -1.46358495e-16,  3.56382552e-03,  1.03861543e-01],
         [ 4.60463491e-02,  2.85696738e-02,  4.25652937e-17, ...,
           7.52233837e-17,  1.52561546e-02, -4.53776133e-02],
         [ 3.36192439e-02,  6.09961875e-02, -2.38046403e-16, ...,
          -1.06114358e-16,  1.39832846e-01,  1.23731435e-02],
         [ 4.77920265e-17,  3.49655673e-17, -9.88879943e-04, ...,
           6.57132771e+00,  9.11115149e-17,  4.00803440e-16],
         [-4.57024983e-18, -1.95414769e-17, -2.05300777e-02, ...,
          -3.10520949e-02, -5.30893022e-17,  2.67644214e-19]],

        [[-2.26920292e-17, -2.60031530e-17,  1.59090454e-04, ...,
           1.95846665e-04, -1.08377845e-16,  8.12772173e-17],
         [ 4.02892829e-17,  2.80316603e-17,  1.36933468e-03, ...,
           1.35174553e-03,  5.91020123e-17, -3.74021590e-17],
         [ 3.13760901e-17,  6.10726210e-17,  5.73656461e-03, ...,
           3.33108195e-04,  1.07534704e-16,  1.50073155e-17],
         [-2.55815025e-02, -5.06584131e-02,  2.62220010e-16, ...,
           9.11115149e-17,  6.56828103e+00, -5.35839140e-04],
         [ 1.28679373e-17,  4.17923336e-17, -1.71985296e-17, ...,
          -2.59620518e-17,  2.73187335e-16,  5.15672840e-19]],

        [[-3.12834270e-17, -2.52199046e-17, -1.52071873e-02, ...,
          -3.08303159e-02, -2.49025578e-17,  3.16651901e-16],
         [ 3.66728694e-17,  2.49191624e-17, -4.73928990e-03, ...,
           2.84855602e-02,  3.25611936e-17, -5.06419642e-17],
         [ 3.21225801e-17,  5.14665331e-17,  9.55766799e-04, ...,
          -6.58471582e-03,  1.12056604e-16,  3.67158060e-17],
         [ 2.91869574e-03,  6.40882246e-03,  1.27034545e-16, ...,
           4.00803440e-16, -5.35839140e-04,  6.80976592e+01],
         [ 2.51073576e-20, -6.49867240e-18, -1.34571841e-17, ...,
          -1.27197531e-17, -1.58327480e-18,  3.08637653e-16]]],


       [[[ 4.52641078e-17,  1.91883698e-17, -4.29118594e-04, ...,
          -3.41887510e-03,  1.38145177e-17, -2.27258802e-18],
         [-4.57741656e-18, -3.59978088e-18,  1.26438979e-03, ...,
          -1.48149818e-03, -3.02944995e-18,  3.82585897e-19],
         [ 5.34778447e-18,  6.91639776e-18, -6.20845224e-04, ...,
           2.67824552e-04, -5.05176956e-19, -1.15520124e-18],
         [ 1.00578809e-16,  2.58339687e-18, -1.10886189e-17, ...,
          -4.57024983e-18,  5.20359913e-18,  4.17752327e-18],
         [ 4.60301317e-01, -8.14036526e-02,  1.37279292e-16, ...,
           4.15740027e-17, -2.55815025e-02,  2.91869574e-03]],

        [[ 2.05773995e-17,  6.69254025e-17, -1.12269482e-03, ...,
          -3.69589233e-03,  3.29116066e-17, -5.28719242e-18],
         [-9.69989436e-18, -9.52942963e-18, -2.00282275e-03, ...,
           1.67213241e-03, -6.65286767e-18,  4.14226871e-18],
         [-2.74096172e-18, -1.03426735e-18,  1.55725811e-05, ...,
          -4.98067295e-04, -7.31259464e-18, -2.38172811e-18],
         [ 6.23078709e-18,  1.77609190e-16, -2.68748156e-17, ...,
          -1.95414769e-17,  2.65795987e-17, -7.30736039e-18],
         [-8.14036526e-02,  7.71163480e-01,  4.81915926e-17, ...,
          -2.25751979e-17, -5.06584131e-02,  6.40882246e-03]],

        [[ 1.63839318e-03,  7.74373617e-04,  1.19373172e-16, ...,
           8.57034652e-17, -3.07852940e-04, -3.95005722e-03],
         [-6.68854761e-03, -7.38468872e-03, -8.68165242e-18, ...,
          -2.16513251e-17, -1.23273914e-03,  5.99585156e-03],
         [-1.02165471e-02, -1.44553312e-02,  6.67430243e-17, ...,
           3.18508566e-17, -1.55376354e-02, -1.60850158e-03],
         [-9.16038717e-18, -7.54993775e-18, -2.94424850e-02, ...,
          -2.05300777e-02, -1.71985296e-17, -1.34571841e-17],
         [ 1.37279292e-16,  4.81915926e-17,  1.27266321e+00, ...,
          -1.42489553e-01,  1.37493221e-16,  1.07264061e-17]],

        ...,

        [[ 2.65783872e-03,  1.74527603e-03,  7.41740010e-17, ...,
           2.29138501e-16, -6.58581972e-04, -1.91932348e-02],
         [-8.50919755e-03, -5.27957162e-03, -2.70587404e-17, ...,
          -3.95632533e-17, -2.81928179e-03,  8.38561761e-03],
         [-6.21271380e-03, -1.12718732e-02,  6.27926127e-17, ...,
           7.22678661e-17, -2.58406006e-02, -2.28651184e-03],
         [-3.68031176e-18, -1.71380598e-17, -2.65470468e-02, ...,
          -3.10520949e-02, -2.59620518e-17, -1.27197531e-17],
         [ 4.15740027e-17, -2.25751979e-17, -1.42489553e-01, ...,
           6.40903189e+00, -3.51206002e-17,  2.60883987e-16]],

        [[ 2.02358655e-17,  3.11500512e-17, -2.21670265e-05, ...,
          -3.61917502e-05,  2.14013831e-16, -3.46312768e-17],
         [-2.57769958e-17, -2.31599852e-17, -1.90797609e-04, ...,
          -2.49797649e-04, -4.17740399e-17,  1.55155698e-17],
         [-1.27902235e-17, -1.55470256e-17, -7.99309931e-04, ...,
          -6.15571808e-05,  9.49891379e-18,  3.47233490e-18],
         [ 3.94605342e-18,  2.33604087e-17, -5.64843710e-17, ...,
          -5.30893022e-17,  2.56636736e-16, -2.78181454e-18],
         [-2.55815025e-02, -5.06584131e-02,  1.37493221e-16, ...,
          -3.51206002e-17,  6.56828103e+00, -5.35839140e-04]],

        [[ 7.37224457e-19,  9.65125128e-19,  2.11890856e-03, ...,
           5.69733006e-03,  1.62670658e-18,  4.02013294e-16],
         [ 2.64951838e-18,  1.32364578e-18,  6.60353668e-04, ...,
          -5.26402774e-03, -5.40082544e-18, -3.41171246e-17],
         [ 4.73676722e-18,  1.09268624e-17, -1.33172717e-04, ...,
           1.21683149e-03, -3.17451065e-18,  8.34355852e-17],
         [ 2.66720636e-18, -3.05203045e-18,  1.08869356e-17, ...,
           2.67644214e-19, -1.66373105e-18,  1.97142740e-16],
         [ 2.91869574e-03,  6.40882246e-03,  1.07264061e-17, ...,
           2.60883987e-16, -5.35839140e-04,  6.80976592e+01]]]])
```

## If you want only A and not B

Since you're doing the TDA approximation instead of a full TD-DFT calculation, you are probably trying to save RAM or CPU time by not using the $B$ matrix, so you might not want to calculate it at all. Hopefully there is a better way to do this, but based on looking at [the `get_ab` function in PySCF's `tdscf/uhf.py`](https://github.com/tepl/pyscf/blob/master/pyscf/tdscf/uhf.py#L113), one way that I can see to avoiding calculating the $B$ matrix is to remove or comment all lines leading to the obtaining of the `b` output. For I would remove the last line, and all lines related to `b_aa`, `b_ab`, or `b_bb` out of the following lines:

```
    a_aa = numpy.diag(e_ia_a.ravel()).reshape(nocc_a,nvir_a,nocc_a,nvir_a)
    a_bb = numpy.diag(e_ia_b.ravel()).reshape(nocc_b,nvir_b,nocc_b,nvir_b)
    a_ab = numpy.zeros((nocc_a,nvir_a,nocc_b,nvir_b))
    b_aa = numpy.zeros_like(a_aa)
    b_ab = numpy.zeros_like(a_ab)
    b_bb = numpy.zeros_like(a_bb)
    a = (a_aa, a_ab, a_bb)
    b = (b_aa, b_ab, b_bb)
```

Comment: How can I confirm the correctness of this A-matrix? I attempted to utilize the A-matrix computed using the sto3g method within the AQAE script (https://github.com/randylewis/QuantumAnnealing/blob/main/AQAE.py). It resulted in a minimum eigenvalue of value=0.5, which significantly contrasts with the output from the following script:
import pyscf
mol = pyscf.M(atom = ‘H 0 0 0.917; F 0 0 0', basis = 'sto3g', symmetry = True,);
myhf = mol.RHF().run();
cisolver = pyscf.fci.FCI(myhf);
print('E(FCI) = %.12f' % cisolver.kernel()[0]);

Comment: @HadeelMoustafa please post a new question, so that you can get an answer from someone else if I am unavailable. I'm driving to Hamilton then Mississauaga today.